# Create cumulative list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame

```
lst = [[1,0],[None,1],[2,0],[2,0],[None,1],[None,1],[3,0],[None,1] ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['id','is_cumulative'])
```

output

```
  id  is_cumulative
0  1.0              0
1  NaN              1
2  2.0              0
3  2.0              0
4  NaN              1
5  NaN              1
6  3.0              0
7  NaN              1
```

I want replace the NaN values to cumulative list for `id` column

```
          id  is_cumulative
0          1              0
1        [1]              1
2          2              0
3          2              0
4     [1, 2]              1
5     [1, 2]              1
6          3              0
7  [1, 2, 3]              1
```

Some explanation:- where ever `is_cumulative` value is 1 we have NaN value for `id` column as we need to calculate the cumulative list of id to replace it.
Data is like new id than cumulative of all previous id occurred till now than again some new id and cumulative of all id's occurred till that row.

Comment: why row 4&5 is [1,2] ?

Comment: some id's can repeat multiple times. ID 2 is repeated twice so in the desired output 4&5 is [1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way:

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].fillna(df1['id'].dropna().drop_duplicates()
                                      .astype(int) #this might not be necessary
                                      .apply(lambda x: [x]).cumsum()
                                      .reindex(df1.index, method='ffill'))
print(df1)

          id  is_cumulative
0          1              0
1        [1]              1
2          2              0
3          2              0
4     [1, 2]              1
5     [1, 2]              1
6          3              0
7  [1, 2, 3]              1
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try only with the id with `dropna` and drop the duplicate , `cumsum` the result then `reindex` and `fillna`

```
s = (df1.id.dropna().drop_duplicates().astype(str)+',').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',').reindex(df1.index).ffill()
df1.id = df1.id.fillna(s)
df1
Out[425]: 
                id  is_cumulative
0                1              0
1            [1.0]              1
2                2              0
3                2              0
4       [1.0, 2.0]              1
5       [1.0, 2.0]              1
6                3              0
7  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]              1
```